# Read Cookie Data from PHP in Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I have a PHP file that contains both the PHP Code and the JQuery Code. My motive is to set cookies as and when the PHP code is executing and read the cookies set by PHP in the JQuery part of the code and make some decision. But I'm not able to do that. What would be the best way for me to achieve this.

I'm new to PHP any help would be great.

```html
<?php>
if(isset($_POST['StartProcess'])){
$Process_step = 1;
setcookie("MyCookie", $Process_step); sleep(30);
$Process_step = 2;
setcookie("MyCookie", $Process_step); sleep(30);}
<?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
window.setInterval(function(){
                    var abc = document.cookie.split(";").map(function(el){ return el.split("="); }).reduce(function(prev,cur){ prev[cur[0]] = cur[1];return prev },{});
                    console.log(abc["MyCookie"]);
if(Step == 1){ do something;}else if(Step == 1){ do something else;}
})
})</script>
<head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to use PHP session value on the JQuery.

You can print the variable of PHP in the JQuery line. You can do it like this

`var myvalue = "<?PHP $phpvarname ?>"`

or you can use PHP session and assign it on the var.

Comment: I have a question. Say i post a a form data to php from my html form, is there a possibility that i can read the data from php during the POST request execution?

Comment: PHP is an interpreted language. This means that you will write code statements (lines of code) and when a page is requested, the PHP interpreter will load your PHP code, parse it and then execute it.
Simply means that scripts are read from top to bottom, so yes?
[link](https://stillat.com/blog/2014/04/02/how-does-php-work-with-the-web-server-and-browser#:~:text=The%20Language,is%20compiled%20and%20then%20executed.)